# Using Tkinter to open a webpage

Tags: python, tkinter

So my App needs to be able to open a single webpage(and it must be from the internet and not saved) in it, and specifically I'd like to use the Tkinter GUI toolkit since it's the one i'm most comfortable with. On top of that though, I'd like to be able to generate events in the window(say a mouse click) but without actually using the mouse. What's a good method to go about this?

**EDIT:** I suppose to clarify this a bit, I need a way to load a webpage, or maybe even a specific java applet into a tkinter widget or window. Or if not that perhaps another method to do this where I can generate mouse and keyboard events without using either the mouse of the keyboard.

Comment: If the webpage is really simple, use Tkhtml (http://tkhtml.tcl.tk) and python bindings for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to be opened inside your GUI use Bryans suggestion, if you just want to open a webpage you can use:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("page.html")
```

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter does not have a widget that can render a web page.

Comment: Would there be a way to display it via some other method?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `pywebview` it is very easy only code three lines .

I used it but in my case it didn't work everywhere. Comment and let me know if it works for you.

The best option that works everywhere is `PyQt`'s `QtWebview` module. You might run into one problem that is to rename the window, so here is the solution

```
web.setWindowTitle(title)
```

You can use all the functions as it is but just replace `window` or `self` with `web` like the above code.

Comment: Hey! Could you please share an example of code of how do think pywebview should work in this case? or maybe a link to a related post?

Comment: I would like you to go through [how do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and please make the changes. Your answer fails to explain why "*it didn't work everywhere*" and what was your case, does not include any reference code or links that could be useful in understanding the latter part of your answer. Adding extraneous elements of attention in answers is not encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

So i found this module named pywebview

```
pip install pywebview
```

sample code:-

```
import webview
webview.create_window('duckduckgo', 'https://www.duckduckgo.com')
webview.start() #this will open the webpage in a new window
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! We usually submit answers to questions only if we have a practical solution to the question. References to external resources are usually being submitted as comments. If you do not have enough reputation in order to submit a comment then please wait until you do. An alternative would be writing in your answer a short summary explaining how this module solves the problem along with a code snippet that demonstrate your statement.