# Advertising on a tkinter program

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

My question is : is it possible to put ads on a tkinter program , something like google ads or something , because I made a program which a lot of people started using and I am not getting any benefits from it , is there a way ?

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: What do ylu mean by tried something ? I have done some extensive research and didn't seem to find anything on this subject...

Comment: So you want to add another widget to your interface to show some changing HTML-content?

Comment: Yes we can put it that way

Comment: Take a look at this post. They say it is not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076674/using-tkinter-to-open-a-webpage

Comment: Why isn't it possible? Embed a small browser inside the app and display ads

Comment: Has anyone considered using "tkhtml" ? Or is that a bad idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing built-in to tkinter, nor available as a third party library, that makes it possible to display an ad and receive revenue from it.

Comment: Like I asked in the comment above , how about using tkhtml ?

Comment: @Amroelaswar: you can try, but tkhtml died a long time ago. It was never made it past an alpha stage and hasn't been updated in many years.

Comment: I see , how about an ad button that will open an advertisement in the browser would something like that be able to be setup with google adsense ? Thanks for your answers by the way

Answer (score 3):

As kind of stated in other answers you could possibly do something like this:

```
import webbrowser

#Activate when user clicks a button that does something else on your program
webbrowser.open("link-to-site-with-ads")
```

This way if you owned the target site every time the user presses a button on your program that needs to be pressed to do something it opens. Another way could be to make it as soon as the program runs it will execute (this may be better as it would frustrate users less). Hope this helps any other people looking at this question.